# Can Firewalld work with the Docker Overlay Network?

Tags: docker

First, I create 2 docker hosts using the following settings:

```
## CLUSTER CONFIGURATION
# Firewall: firewalld
# OS: CentOS7
# IPs:
 - 10.10.2.3
 - 10.10.2.4

# Docker daemons:
/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 \
          --cluster-store=consul://10.10.2.3:8500 \
          --cluster-advertise=10.10.2.3:2375
/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 \
          --cluster-store=consul://10.10.2.3:8500 \
          --cluster-advertise=10.10.2.4:2375
```

Then, I create an overlay network:

```
docker network create -d overlay my-overlay-network
```

Then, I try to ping a container on Node2 from a container on Node1 using the hostname of the container:

```
# ssh 10.10.2.4
docker run --net my-overlay-network --hostname 10-10-2-4-container centos /bin/sh -c 'while true; do sleep 1; done'

# Start firewalld, and open ports on both machines
systemctl start firewalld 
/usr/bin/firewall-cmd \
  # Add Consul ports
  --add-port=8300/tcp \
  --add-port=8301/tcp \
  --add-port=8301/udp \
  --add-port=8302/tcp \
  --add-port=8302/udp \
  --add-port=8400/tcp \
  --add-port=8500/tcp \
  --add-port=8600/tcp \
  --add-port=8600/udp
  # Add Docker ports
  --add-port=2375/tcp \
  --add-port=7946/tcp \
  --add-port=7946/udp \
  --add-port=4789/tcp

# From Node1. This fails! The hostname resolves correctly 
# to the right subnet and IP, but the ping packet doesn't return.
docker run --net my-overlay-network centos ping -c node2-container


# After disabling the firewall, it works fine.
systemctl stop firewalld # From 10.10.2.3
systemctl stop firewalld # From 10.10.2.4
docker run --net my-overlay-network centos ping -c 10-10-2-4-container
```

Basically, it looks like I can't ping my node when the firewall is on. The hostname appears to resolve correctly. *How can I configure my firewall to work with Docker's overlay network?*

Comment: Don't hesitate to criticize my answer, ask for clarification, or provide demos, etc. I really want to get the solution to this problem :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can!

These are the ports that you need to have opened for the overlay network to work w/ a multi-host Docker setup:

```
firewall-cmd \
  --add-port=2375/tcp \
  --add-port=4789/udp \
  --add-port=7946/tcp \
  --add-port=7946/udp
```

The 4789 port is for VXLAN. It operates over UDP. You will also need to open up whatever ports your KV system uses, especially the ones for DNS resolution (Consul listens at 8600 UDP/TCP for DNS resolution).

Comment: So you'd made just the one mistake in opening port 4789 over *tcp* instead of *udp*; and when you fixed that, it all worked?